# Show data from excel table to listbox in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

hello i tried to populate my listbox at my excel sheet but i had a hard time to put a right code in VBA.
[image]
as you can see in this picture the box that marked is my list box. and i have the data table in other sheet called "Data Barang" (sheet2) and i tried to show the data table to the listbox and when i double click the data at the listbox it will pull the selected data row to those text boxes above the listbox. The listbox name and the table name are same which is "DataBarang".
[image]
anyone have reference what code can work for my listbox?
[image]
there's the code i have tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Sheet1.DataBarang
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 14
    .ListFillRange = Sheet2.ListObjects("DataBarang").Range.Select
End With

End Sub
```

-----------------------------------EDITED-----------------------------------

I have success to populate my listbox but it seems cannot filled the column heads. can anybody help me to fill those column heads?
[image]

here is my code that i used

```
Sub loaddata()

Dim listdata As Object
Set listdata = Sheet1.DataBarang
Dim tabeldata As Range
Set tabeldata = Sheet2.Range("DataBarang")

With listdata
    .AutoLoad = True
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 14
    .List = tabeldata.CurrentRegion.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i have update the code i used and the listbox did not show anything

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code. People cannot copy/paste it then.

Comment: sorry i have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't neeed to select the range - but have to pass the adress of the range as string (it always helps to read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.controlformat.listfillrange

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Sheet1.DataBarang
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 14
    .ListFillRange = Sheet2.ListObjects("DataBarang").DataBodyRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
End With

End Sub
```